# Comic where telekinetic teenagers with super powers roam an island 'disconnected' from the mainland

Tags: story-identification, comics, telepathy

I read a fairly lengthy comic series (or maybe a webcomic) about 5 years ago which I forgot the name of. The comic follows half a dozen or so teenagers/young adults all with similar telekinetic powers on a largely uninhabited island overgrown with vegetation (possibly one of British isles?). The island somehow became 'disconnected' and was no longer accessible to and from the rest of the world.

The story follows these characters leading a settlement of survivors, helping them and defending them from attacks. The main characters all have telekinetic powers which allow them to read/alter other people's minds as well as communicate telepathically. Most of these superpowered individuals were 'good' but there was at least one character I remember who had continuously used his powers to effectively rape non-powered survivors and was punished by the other members of the group. (Possibly by having his powers taken away?)

Use of their powers was usually accompanied by some kind of brief eye color change. Their powers in plot were primarily used pointing outwards, but they also seemed to have greater command of their own mind. For example, one character tells another to "sober up" and they're able to do so instantly through use of their powers.

Another specific subplot I remember is that at one point their settlement comes under attack by another, much smaller settlement. After they crush the attack they use their telepathic to ascertain the location of their attacker's settlement. When they come upon it they find starving women and children who, again using their telepathic powers to determine, had used the last of their food to give the attackers a meal so they'd be strong enough to strike. Determining that they were no longer a threat they invite them to their settlement after some arguing.

Spoilers for late in the comic:

> Towards the end it's revealed that the teenagers were the ones responsible for breaking the island off from the rest of the world using their powers in an act of desperation after being cornered by the police. They all commit to 'reconnect' the island and I believe the series end shortly after them doing so.

Comment: Reminds me of _[The Midwich Cuckoos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Midwich_Cuckoos), but it differs on important points. Maybe it's a loose adaptation.

Comment: If it's the work I've suggested below, then the Midwich Cuckoo's was cited as an inspiration for the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be [FreakAngels](http://www.freakangels.com/) (website currently down)?

The titular characters live in a flooded Whitechapel, where they (mostly) help and protect the local community; using their powers to abuse the 'normal' people was a plot point for one of them who was indeed punished. From memory, they had purple eyes - but I can't recall if this was when using their powers or a permanent change.

Your spoiler point was shown as a flashback sequence.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreakAngels) summary:

> Ellis' synopsis of the plot involves characters "living in a post-flood London that they might possibly have had something to do with." The so-called FreakAngels, who possess telepathy and many other "special" abilities, such as space-time manipulation/distortion, and pyrokinesis, live in Whitechapel.

> As the story progresses, eleven of the FreakAngels are introduced and their role in the community is expanded. For the most part cooperatively they have created a small community of roughly three hundred people with fresh water, watch towers, markets, home-grown vegetables and a medical clinic. Their society is threatened, however, externally from refugee attacks and internally from personal conflicts and crime.

Comment: It's definitely FreakAngels. The artwork is exactly how I remember it. Thank you so much!